# dict.get() - default arg evaluated even upon success

Tags: python, dictionary

Why is the default in [`dict.get(key[, default])`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) evaluated even if the key is in the dictionary?

```
>>> key = 'foo'
>>> a={}
>>> b={key:'bar'}
>>> b.get(key, a[key])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    b.get(key, a[key])
KeyError: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 40):

As in any function call, the arguments are evaluated before the call is executed.
In this case `dict.get()` is no exception...

Comment: +1 -- zen of python: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."

Comment: I see the logic but it's a shame that `dict.get` can't be used for caching results of costly computations.  E.g.: `return stored_results.get(x, calculate_result(x))`.

Answer (score 29):

use this instead

```
x = b.get(key) or a.get(key)
```

`or` and `and` are short circuit operators, so if `b` has the key it won't look at `a`. But problems will arise if you have `false` values in `b`. If that is the case you can do:

```
x = b[key] if key in b else a.get(key)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I lost a couple hours debugging this.  Obviously it would short circuit and why would I want to use .get twice if I know I've guaranteed one or the other key?  Bad choice, Python.

Comment: This looks the best (and also pythonic) answer.  I prefer the second one with `if else` since it works for cases where `b[key] = 0`, as referred as "falsy" value case.

Comment: @Starman I'd argue, because it's actually pretty clever, since in every major language `OR` is evaluated lazily. (what is the point to run the second argument evaluation, if the first argument is already `True`?)

Answer (score 10):

You can rewrite the example you gave as

```
b.get(key, a.get(key))
```

to avoid the exception.  This will return `None` if the key is in neither dictionary.  More generally, if you want to avoid the evaluation of the second argument, you could use

```
try:
    x = b[key]
except KeyError:
    x = a[key]   # or whatever the default value is supposed to be
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are evaluating it, then passing it as an argument to `get`. This happens whether or not `get` ends up using the argument.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the lookup you could:

```
value = b.get(key)
if value is None:
   value = a[key]
```

Or if `None` is allowed then:

```
not_set = object()
# ...
value = b.get(key, not_set)
if value is not_set:
   value = a[key]
```

Comment: what if in `# ...`, the user does `b[not_set] = 1`. {trollface}

Comment: @Doboy: nothing happens. `not_set` is a special value, not key.

Answer (score 0):

1. `a[key]` is `a['foo']` and you don't have that key in `a`.
2. this is evaluated before calling `b.get` hence the error
3. "even if the key is in the dictionary" - that's anot true, `b` is empty (but as the 2. points shows, this is not relevant)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `a[key]` bit evaluates before `b.get` (evaluates *eagerly*).

To get around this (evaluate *lazily*), you could write a simple helper function:

```
def lazy_get(d, key, default):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    else:
        v = default()
        return v
```

And use it like so:

```
lazy_get(b, key, lambda: a[key])
```