# Dictionary get method behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {"a": "first", "b": "second"}
```

and it's ok, when I do the following:

```
print dic.get("a")
print dic.get("a", "asd")
print dic.get("a", dic.get("c"))
```

but when I use this method like this:

```
print dic.get("a", dic.get("c").split(" ",1)[0])
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I dont't understand the last case. The second argument calculated (dic.get("c") should be None - it's ok), but there is a key "a" in dictionary and first argument shouldn't fire calculating of the second argument.

How I can fix this? And why it happened?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have explained, Python (like most other languages outside the functional family) evaluates all arguments of a function before calling it. Thus, `dic.get("c")` is `None` when key "c" doesn't exist in the dictionary and `None` has no `.split()` method, and this evaluation happens regardless of whether (and in fact before) the `get` succeeds or fails.

Instead, use a short-circuiting Boolean operator or a conditional expression.

```
# if dic.get["a"] is always truthy when it exists
dic.get("a") or dic.get("c", "").split(" ", 1)[0]

# if dic["a"] could be non-truthy, e.g. empty string
dic["a"] if "a" in dic else dic.get("c", "").split(" ", 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The second argument is always evaluated whether or not it is used.

To fix it you can catch the exception that is raised when an item is not found instead of using `get`.

```
try:
    result = dic['a']
except KeyError:
    result = dic['c'].split(' ', 1)[0]
print result
```

Comment: Thx! And why it's calculated? It's a python feature? I think it's unusefull - why evaluate if it's no need.

Comment: @dizpers: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761396/dict-get-default-arg-evaluated-even-upon-success

Comment: @dizpers: `get` is just an ordinary method like any other. The Python interpreter doesn't look inside the method to see how the parameters are used. Like all ordinary method calls in Python, all the arguments are evaluated before the method call is made. There are only a few situation where not all the arguments are evaluated, e.g. the special `and` and `or` operators that use short-circuiting.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you just have typo and meant

```
print dic.get("a", dic.get("c")).split(" ",1)[0]
```

That is you meant to split the result of the outer `dic.get` not the inner one.

Comment: No, the "a" key always has a value without spaces, but "c" always has a space char.

Answer (score 2):

```
dic.get("c")
```

Your dictionary doesn't contain "c", so it returns `None`.

```
dic.get("c").split(" ",1)[0]
```

Since we know that `dic.get("c")` is `None`:

```
None.split(" ",1)[0]
```

`None` has no `split` method, so that's why you get that error.

The arguments are all evaluated before they're passed to the method.

Comment: I understand this. The question is - why this expression is calculated? The first argument is ok, so .get() method shouldn't work with a second argument.

Comment: @dizpers - The interpreter needs to know all of the arguments before it calls the function. Some languages use [Lazy Evalutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), which means they only evaluate something when they need it, but Python is not one of those languages.